# Multi condition filtering with checkboxes JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filtering, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a filter based that is triggered by checkboxes, which shows and hides options from a list. I have tried to use resources online to put the script together but nothing seems to work.

In order to hide or show list items
I am editing a - class= "marker" parent element
based on wether - class= "condtx" of its child element
is matching the array of checked boxes "value" or not.

I have included comments on how I am proceeding.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```js
function filterCondtn1() {
  var i, z;

  //"chekedVal" array Keeps returning "undefined" I have no idea why

  var chekedVal = document.getElementById("InputOpts").getElementsByTagName("input").checked.value;

  //Gathered all <h3> tag options into array to be tested against "chekedVal" for match

  var condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("condtn1").innerHTML;

  //Parrent class that will be edited to show <div> or not if True or false.

  var parrentClss = document.getElementsByClassName("marker");

  //From here it's a blur. I've trying everything I can. I think I should be something of that sort.

  for {
    (var i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) &&
    (var z = 0; z < parrentClss.length; z++)
    RemoveClass(parrentClss[z], "show");
    if (condt1[i].indexOf(chekedVal) > -1) AddClass(parrentClss[z], "show");
  }
}

//Currently using these two functions in my script and they work

function RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

function AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.markerA {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="InputOpts">
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 1" oninput="filterCondtn1();">Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 2" oninput="filterCondtn1();">Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 3" oninput="filterCondtn1();">Option 3
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 4" oninput="filterCondtn1();">Option 4
</div>

<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn1">Option 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn2">Option 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn1">Option 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn2">Option 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code has a lot of issues. Please edit it to limit a specific problem.  The full article is here: How to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of your onInput function. This can be done with alot less code than you have. You can just grab elements directly without looping through the checkboxes and parent elements. You can also add direct stylings without having to go through the nonsense of adding css classes.

Im not 100% sure what you wanted so here is two examples.

If you want to hide the selected options :

```js
function filterCondtn1(event) {
  var element = event.target
  var condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("option")
  for (var i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) {
    if (condt1[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = "display:none"
      } else {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = "display:block"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="InputOpts">
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 1" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 2" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 3" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 3
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 4" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 4
</div>

<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to show only selected options:

```js
function filterCondtn1(event) {
  var element = event.target
  var condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("option")
  for (var i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) {
    if (condt1[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = "display:block"
      } else {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = "display:none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.marker > .necessary {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="InputOpts">
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 1" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 2" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 3" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 3
  <input type="checkbox" value="option 4" oninput="filterCondtn1(event);">Option 4
</div>

<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="option">Option 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selectOption(self){
  const value = self.value;
  unCheckPreviousOption(value);
  const element = document.getElementsByClassName(value)[0];
  element.classList.remove('marker');
  element.classList.add('show');
}

function unCheckPreviousOption(currentCheckbox){
  uncheckCheckboxes(currentCheckbox);
  const elementsDisplayed = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
  if(elementsDisplayed.length){
    [...elementsDisplayed].forEach((el) => {
      el.classList.remove('show');
      el.classList.add('marker');
    });
  }
}

function uncheckCheckboxes(currentCheckbox){
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if(checkboxes.length){
    [...checkboxes].forEach((el) => {
      if(el.checked && el.value !== currentCheckbox){
        el.checked = !el.checked;
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

```css
.show { 
  display: block;
}

.marker { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="InputOpts">
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="selectOption(this)" value="one">Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="selectOption(this)" value="two">Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="selectOption(this)" value="three">Option 3
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="selectOption(this)" value="four">Option 4
</div>

<div class="marker one">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn1">Option 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="marker three">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn2">Option 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker two">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn1">Option 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="marker four">
  <div class="necessary">
    <h3 class="condtn2">Option 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

This might help you out, it's a different way of achieving what you want to do.