# Angular 10+ checkbox filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, filtering

I'm trying to implement multiple checkbox filtering using Angular but can't seem to be able to figure out how to proceed exactly. I've looked over multiple similar questions here, but failed to figure out how to use any of the answers.

Ideally, I'd like to filter my data using event listeners.

My main two issues are:

1. Figuring out how to actually filter things, I can't figure out what the right approach would be for my goal
2. Actually displaying updated data

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1mjhnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilters%2Ffilters.component.ts)

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695113/multi-condition-filtering-with-checkboxes-javascript), you retrieve once the data then make filtered copy you pass to your component

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions in one question, which is not suitable for SO. Try https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to share the data(`filters`) between two components because `filtered-users` and `filters` are two components in your project. 
so, to share `data` between two `components` (which are not having `parent-child` relationship) we can use [observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular).

You can create a service called `FilterService` and in that, you can have an `observable` (filters)

```
@Injectable()
export class FilterService {
     private filters = new Subject<{}>(); // creating a subject

     filters$ = this.filters.asObservable(); // creating an observable

     alertFilter(key: string, value: string) {
         this.filters.next({ key, value }); // publishing the new fliter to the subscribers
     }
}
```

and add this `service` to `filtered-users`, `filters` components through `dependency-injection`. and call this `alertFilter()` method of `FilterService` from `filters` component whenever the user checks the filter checkbox.

in filter.component.html

```
<input (change)="onCheck('gender', opt)"
```

in filter.component.ts

```
onCheck(key: string, value: string) {
   this.filterService.alertFilter(key, value);
}
```

after this, subscribe to the `observable`(filters) of `FilterService` in `filtered-users-component`.

in filtered-users.component.ts

```
constructor(
  private sortingService: SortingService,
  private userService: UserService,
  private filterService: FilterService
) {
     this.filterService.filters$.subscribe({
        next: filter => {
               this.filteredUsers = this.filteredUsers.filter(user => {
                    return user[filter['key']] === filter['value'];
               });
        }
     });
}
```

`this.filterService.filters$.subscribe()` will execute whenever a new filter has been added so, using filter variable you can filter the users accordingly.